# Find the IP address of expired domains

Tags: web-hosting, dns

I want to know the previous hosting IP address of an expired domain. Is there any way find this?

Answer (score 6):

The well named [DNS History](http://dnshistory.org/) tool should give you what you are after.

Comment: I like the idea of this, however, the history seems to be surprisingly sparse/non-existent for the domains I've tried?!

Answer (score 1):

Other useful sources besides dnshistory.org:

- https://viewdns.info/reverseip/ 250 queries per free account
- 2013 DNS census: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1951/dataset-of-domain-names/21077#21077

Both of these tend to contain more data than dnshistory.org. The data of these three sources is disjoint however, so searching all of them can be fruitful.

Another one is: https://securitytrails.com/dns-trails appears to be the most complete one I've seen so far. I believe without great evidence that they have pieced up other databases together. Signup blacklists common email providers like gmail to force professional accounts. Query limit appears to be 100/day.

Related: https://superuser.com/questions/686195/how-to-find-the-last-ip-used-for-an-expired-domain-name